# Display checked value of db from one page to other

Tags: php, html

I fetched data from DB and show it in the table with checkboxes, now I want to show the checked rows of one page into the table on another page .my code on another page not working correctly and not showing the data.

here is code to fetch data and show in the table with a checkbox on the first page.

```
<form method="post" action="other.php">
    <table  border="2px" align="center">
        <tr >
            <th width="100">ID</th>
            <th width="200">Item</th>
            <th width="100">Price</th>
            <th  width="200"></th>
        </tr>
        <?php
            $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","hotal");
            if($conn-> connect_error){
                die("Connection field:". $conn-> connection_error);
            }
            $sql="SELECT id,item,price from beverages";
            $result=$conn->query($sql);

            if($result->num_rows>0){
                while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
                echo"<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["item"]."</td> 
                <td>".$row["price"]."</td><td>"."<input type='checkbox' name='menu[]' 
                value=>".$row["item"]."</td></tr>"; 
            }
            echo"</table>"; }else {
            echo"0 result"; }
            $conn->close();
        ?>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

here is a code of the second page where I want to show checked values of the first page in the table

```
<table  border="2px" align="center">
    <tr >
        <th width="100">ID</th> 
        <th width="200">Item</th>
        <th width="100">Price</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
        $name=$_POST['menu'];
        foreach ($name as $row) {
            echo"<tr><td>".$row."</td><td>".$row."</td><td>".$row."</td></tr>";
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: _"I want to show checked values of the first page"_ - there are no values, because you messed up the HTML on that first page to begin with. `<input type='checkbox' name='menu[]' value=>` - so what exact value do you expect this to send now ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below correction code and try it.

```
<form method="post" action="other.php">
    <table  border="2px" align="center">
        <tr >
            <th width="100">ID</th>
            <th width="200">Item</th>
            <th width="100">Price</th>
            <th  width="200"></th>
        </tr>
        <?php
            $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","hotal");
            if($conn-> connect_error){
                die("Connection field:". $conn-> connection_error);
            }
            $sql="SELECT id,item,price from beverages";
            $result=$conn->query($sql);

            if($result->num_rows>0){
                while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
                $values = $row["id"].'|'.$row["item"].'|'.$row["price"];
                echo"<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["item"]."</td> 
                <td>".$row["price"]."</td><td>"."<input type='checkbox' name='menu[]' 
                value=".$values."></td></tr>"; 
            }
            echo"</table>"; }else {
            echo"0 result"; }
            $conn->close();
        ?>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Now to Get Id, Item and price use explode you can see below.

Second Page :

```
<table  border="2px" align="center">
    <tr >
        <th width="100">ID</th> 
        <th width="200">Item</th>
        <th width="100">Price</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
        $name=$_POST['menu'];
        foreach ($name as $row) {
            $values = explode("|",$row);
            echo"<tr><td>".$values[0]."</td><td>".$values[1]."</td><td>".$values[2]."</td></tr>";
        }
    ?>
</table>
```